# What is the difference for apache virtualhost syntax?

Tags: apache, ssl, vhosts

I setup SSL vhost for two different domains with different syntax. The two files syntax are,

**file1: example.test.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/htdocs
ServerName example.test.com
<Directory "/var/www/example.org/htdocs">
allow from all
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/htdocs
ServerName example.test.com
<Directory "/var/www/example.org/htdocs">
allow from all
Options -Indexes
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/example_org.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/example_org.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**file2: example.dev.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.org/htdocs"
ServerName example.dev.com
<Directory "/var/www/example.org/htdocs">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.org/htdocs"
ServerName example.dev.com
<Directory "/var/www/example.org/htdocs">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/STAR_dev_org.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/dev.key
</VirtualHost>
```

The difference between those two files are,

```
file1: DocumentRoot /var/www/example.org/htdocs
file2: DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.org/htdocs"

file1: Options -Indexes
flie2: Options +Indexes

file1: SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/example_org.crt
flie2: SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/STAR_dev_org.crt

file1: SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/example_org.key
flie2: SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.key/dev.key
```

After setup this files, restarted the Apache server and run the two domains,

```
1) http://www.example.test.com and https://www.example.test.com 
2) http://www.example.dev.com and https://www.example.dev.com
```

First domain is working in both http and https, but second domain doesn't work in http.

Is there any syntax to follow for the config file creation? Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Check your server logs for why it “doesn’t work”.

Comment: Did you check the Apache documentation regarding configuration file syntax, and description of configuration parameters?

Comment: I got this error, RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `example.org' does NOT match server name!?